# My mini cart is not removing the image in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am currently trying to change the image layout for my mini-cart. What I am trying to do here is to remove the default image size and replace it with the custom size that I set for the image. This is basically what I added the filter in my function.php.
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_false' );`

It seems the image cannot be removed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Information lacking.. Although that code could have worked, but that will only work if that filter is being used by the current theme.

Comment: Hi Reigel, thanks for the reply. I had tested out and it works for my review-order and cart section but it seems it does not have any effect for my mini-cart which the image is shown below.

Comment: then seems to me, your mini cart don't have that filter in it. only on `review-order` and `cart`. mini cart by the way is not a default woocommerce feature. You can look into the theme code for that.

Comment: I had tested to run and it just has the effect on review order and cart section but my mini-cart stays the same.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/h?preview=issue.PNG)

Comment: Alright noted thanks.